# Why does super().__init__ not work when subclassing threading.Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I wrote a simple program to use threads by subclassing `threading.Thread`. But if I use `super()` to call the `__init__` method of its parent class, namely `threading.Thread`, I got this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'group'
```

If I use `threading.Thread.__init__()` directly, then there are no errors.

My code:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(),
                 kwargs=None, verbose=None):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(self, group=group, target=target,
                                       name=name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs,
                                       verbose=verbose)
        # threading.Thread.__init__(self, group=group, target=target,
        #                           name=name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs,
        #                           verbose=verbose)
        self.args = args

    def run(self):
        print('a thread %d' % (self.args[0],))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in xrange(5):
        thread = MyThread(args=(i,))
        thread.start()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are passing in `self` for the first parameter; don't do this. Remove `self` from the argument list and your call will work:

```
super(MyThread, self).__init__(group=group, target=target,
                               name=name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs,
                               verbose=verbose)
```

`super()` gives you a *bound* method, `self` is already being passed in for you (it is taken from the second argument to `super()`).

Since `group` is the first positional parameter in the `Thread.__init__()` method signature (after `self`), Python is applying your surplus `self` argument to the `group` parameter, and then finds an explicit `group=group` argument as well.

Comment: Threads are confusing all on their own. Someone just *had* to put `super` into the mix.